# imp : symbol lookup error : undefined symbol sldext

Tags: linux, oracle, sqlplus

I trying to import a dump file from app server to db server using code below in linux environment :

```
imp usrname/password FULL=y file=filepath log=log.log
```

when i execute the script in db server, it works well. However, when i use this in app server. it show " imp: symbol lookup error: imp : undefined symbol : sldext". I've checked the app server sqlplus client release is using the same version as db server 11.2.0.4.0. the only difference is under the copyright (c) 1982, App server is using 2011 and DB server is using 2013 instead.

Kindly advice is there any method to allow app server to imp dump file to db server

Comment: have you got an oracle client on your app server. does it have the imp executable? is it in you path?

Comment: yes. when i execute "imp" , it will lead me to input username and password, and further ask me import data only , after that i hit this erro "undefined symbol : sldext"

Answer (score 0):

> when i execute the script in db server, it works well. However, when i use this in app server. it show " imp: symbol lookup error: imp : undefined symbol : sldext"

Impdp or IMP(deprecated) doesn't work on a client machine(in your case the App server) because...

> Data Pump is server-based, rather than client-based, dump files, log files, and SQL files are accessed relative to server-based directory paths. Data Pump requires you to specify directory paths as directory objects. A directory object maps a name to a directory path on the file system.

[Overview of Oracle Data Pump](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14215/dp_overview.htm)